# braintree dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod not returning anything

Tags: javascript, braintree

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Checkout</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="dropin-container"></div>
   <button id="submit-button">Purchase</button>

   <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.3.1/js/dropin.min.js"></script>

   <script>
     var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

     braintree.dropin.create({
       authorization: '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',
       selector: '#dropin-container'
     }, function (err, dropinInstance) {
       if (err) {
         // Handle any errors that might've occurred when creating Drop-in
         console.error(err);
         return;
       }
       submitButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
         dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
           if (err) {
             // Handle errors in requesting payment method
           }
  if(!err){
   console.log(payload);
  }
           // Send payload.nonce to your server
         });
       });
     });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

so basically the `console.log(payload)` not printing any nonce but in network i am able to see that a http call is going on https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/69bcjy9ztbks5z9c/client_api/v1/payment_methods/credit_cards and i can see that there is a card details and nonce but its not printing on console .  tested on firefox , chrome same

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to post your auth key on SO?

Comment: its a demo auth

Comment: Ah that's good. Phew 

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ any idea about the issue :)

Comment: @NilasisSen is this logging any object to the console?

Comment: no its not logging anything thats the problem .u can check and run the code

Comment: @NilasisSen I've ran this code and it was operating as expected, as well as logging the payload/nonce.  Do you have any filters enabled to only show specific errors in your console?  Based on BT's server logs, it appears you are successfully tokenizing your DropIn instance.

Comment: i saw the nonce on the network but on console i am unable to print anything like after getting that nonce i will that request to my server right ? but i am unable to see the nonce